# How to return "" OR empty when value of float is 1

Tags: c++, output

```
void ComplexNum::printComplexNum()
{
    if (imaginary = 1)
    {
        return ""; //cannot return "" I've also tried imaginary == ""; to no avail
    }
    cout << "(" << noshowpos << real << showpos << imaginary << "i)" << endl;
}
```

I have a complex number program, and when I want to display complex numbers it shows them incorrectly in the sense that (4-1i) should be shown as (4-i). While (4-1i) is technically correct, it is not displayed like I want it to be displayed. I created a simple if-statement inside a print method but it is not working because the variable imaginary is not a string. *How do I make it so that when my variable `imaginary` is equal to 1 that it returns "" or blank or nothing so that it can just print out the appropriate "i)" that I have set.

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
First Complex Number:
Enter real part of complex number: 2
Enter imaginary part of complex number: -3
Form '(a+bi)': (2-3i)

Second Complex Number:
Enter real part of complex number: 4
Enter imaginary part of complex number: -4
Form '(a+bi)': (4-4i)

The addition of the two Complex Numbers is: (6-7i)
The difference of the two Complex Numbers is: (-2+1i)
The product of the two Complex Numbers is: (-4-20i)
First Complex Number Squared: (-5-12i)
Second Complex Number Squared: (0-32i)
```

Notice how the difference is (-2+1i)...I don't like that. I don't want that. Also, I don't want that (0-32i). So basically when it's 0 or when it's 1 I would like the print function to reflect that. So the difference would look like (-2+i) and the Second Complex Num Squared would look like (32i)

Now onto my code:

```
class ComplexNum
{
public:
    ComplexNum(float = 0.0, float = 0.0); //default constructor that uses default arg. in case no init. are in main
    void getComplexNum(); //get real and imaginary numbers from keyboard
    void sum(ComplexNum a, ComplexNum b); //method to add two ComplexNum numbers together
    void diff(ComplexNum a, ComplexNum b); //method to find the difference of two complex numbers
    void prod(ComplexNum a, ComplexNum b); //method to find the product of two complex numbers
    void square(); //squares values of a and b when called in main
    void printComplexNum(); //print sum, diff, prod, square 
    void formComplexNum(); //and "a+bi" form


private: 
    float real; //float data member for real number (to be entered in by user)
    float imaginary; //float data member for imaginary number (to be entered in by user)
    float realSquare; //squared real number data member for square method
    float imaginarySquare; //squared imaginary number data member for square method
};
```

And the driver:

```
int main()
{
    ComplexNum a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
    cout << "First Complex Number:" << endl;
    a.getComplexNum();
    a.formComplexNum();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Second Complex Number:" << endl;
    b.getComplexNum();
    b.formComplexNum();
    cout << endl;

    c.sum(a, b);  
    c.printComplexNum();

    d.diff(a, b);
    d.printComplexNum();

    e.prod(a, b);
    e.printComplexNum();

    cout << "First Complex Number Squared: ";
    a.square();
    cout << "Second Complex Number Squared: ";
    b.square();
    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You assign the value 1 to the variable in the if condition. Why not using another output in the if?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You seem to be unfamiliar with what `return` means.

Comment: I wrote return and other things. Yes, I know return does not work in a void. Since a void doesn't return anything. But still. Just an if statement doesn't work here either.

Comment: I think people just glossed over the comment I wrote on that line. I mention specifically I tried "imaginary = ""; " and that didnt' work either. Just trying to point out that I've tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have marked this as C++

> (4-1i) should be shown as (4-i)

You might find std::stringstream helpful.  It simplifies the special handling for the imaginary part:

```
virtual int foo()
{
   std::cout << std::endl;
   show(4, -2);
   show(5, -1);

   return(0);
}

void show(int real, int imaginary)
{
   std::stringstream ss; // default is blank
   if      (-1 == imaginary)   { ss << "-i)"; }
   else /* (-1 != imaginary)*/ { ss << imaginary << "i)"; }

   std::cout << "("
             << std::noshowpos << real
             << std::showpos   << ss.str()
             << std::endl;
}
```

with output

> ```
> (4-2i) 
> (5-i)
> ```

Comment: I have to be methodical about the printing. No shortcuts. thanks Doug.

Comment: I see your requirements changed while I was checking my code.  So I did not handle some of the requirements for real, but the idea is the same ... separate the efforts into manageable parts (perhaps into ssR and ssI), handle each in the simplest way (perhaps if clauses), then combine the strings.  Good luck.

Comment: No need for imaginary to be 'stringstream-ified' before the real.  I just wanted both parts to be completed before starting the std::cout clause.  I prefer the cout clause to be without breaks during operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
void ComplexNum::printComplexNum()
{
    if (imaginary == -1 && real == 0)
    { cout << "(-i)" << endl; }
    else if (imaginary == 1 && real == 0)
    { cout << "(i)" << endl; }
    else if (imaginary == -1)
    { cout << "(" << noshowpos << real << "-i)" << endl; }
    else if (imaginary == 1)
    { cout << "(" << noshowpos << real << "+i)" << endl; }
    else if (real == 0 && imaginary == 0)
    { cout << "(0)" << endl; }
    else if (real == 0)
    { cout << "(" << noshowpos << imaginary << "i)" << endl; }
    else if (imaginary == 0)
    { cout << "(" << noshowpos << real << ")" << endl; }
    else
    { cout << "(" << noshowpos << real << showpos << imaginary << "i)" << endl; }

}
```

Accounts for -1i, 1i, 0i, 0real, both 0i and 0real
The ultimate if-else block. There's no other way around this.

Comment: MMMM....I get aroused looking at my own answer. Just look at how s e x y that code is! I mean seriously. Is there no better way to account for every scenario of ugly-looking imaginary number form? Ugh, I guess if I can't delete my own question, I may as well praise my own answer. Just look at it though. It's the stuff of intro programming godliness. Whatchu know about my else-if block thoooo????

Answer (score -1):

First, when you're checking if two things are equal, you want to use == or .equals(). In this case you want ==, because you're comparing primitives.
Next, this function is a void function. That means you've defined it as not returning anything, but you're trying to return an empty string.
What you want to do is print one pattern when `imaginary` is 1, and a different pattern when `imaginary` isn't 1. Use a print statement, like you do in your default case, to print the special case where `imaginary` = 1.

Comment: When I try using a traditional if-else block when imaginary = 1 and else, then it doesn't print out the statements properly because the showpos isn't triggered by a string. It's just a big mess. I don't know how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Post what you're trying, along with the output.